# route and route_hierarchical default handler

Tags: routes, dart

I have managed to use the packages route and route_hierarchical to handle navigation in a polymer application. However, maybe because I don't speak RegExp natively, I could not find a way to define a default handler called when no matcher matches the path.

As an example I'd like to be able to handle when an arbitrary path is entered directly in the url such as

```
mywebsite.com#/some/path/with/any/number/of/segments
```

or when using go (route_hierarchical) or goToPath (route)

I guess I'm missing something rather straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide more information (route configuration for example)

Comment: I was not very clear. The content is dynamic. Let's assume that I want to fetch data from S3 or Google Storage, following a path given in the hash part of the url. I cannot manage to have an handler called every time the hash is changed (the default handler is called only once and not until another route is matched). I ended up using onHashChange directly to manually parse the hash the way I want it. I thought route could help here. And actually onHashChange gives me everything I want...

Answer (score 0):

I you're using the `route` library, all you have to do is have a route that matches anything at the end of your routes:

```dart
Router router = new Router();
router.addHandler(new UrlPattern(r'/'), myHandler1); // Homepage
router.addHandler(new UrlPattern(r'/fish/'), myHandler2); // Fish page
router.addHandler(new UrlPattern(r'/(.+)'), myHandler3); // Everything else
router.listen()
```

Comment: The issue I wanted to raise is that in the example you proposed, myHandler3 will called only once and if we change the hash again (if using useFragment: true) that matches nothing but "everything else", the handler is not called again. The issue can easily be seen when using route_hierchical github example and changing manually the hash in the address bar to dummy values (#/dummy1, #/dumm2): the default handler is only called the first time

Comment: @alextk I can't reproduce that; though my handler only worked when I put brackets in (I used `new UrlPattern(r'/(.+)')), but it did fire every time and call my handler correctly. Can you easily provide a small-but-working repro?

Comment: The easiest is to play with the example from route_hierachical example.html at https://github.com/angular/route.dart/tree/master/example/basic.
Just enter manually the following hash in the address bar and look at the console: #/one => showOne, #/two => showTwo, #/three => showOne (ok that's the default handler), #/four => (nothing happen here, which is the issue I'm trying to show, which is maybe a feature)